# C++ linked list- class implementation

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

Hey I have build an implementation of linked list in c++ using List class and inner node struct.
everything works fine except removing node from tail function:

```
void  List::remove_tail()
{
    Node* runPtr= new Node;
    runPtr = this->head;
    while(runPtr->next->next !=nullptr) //this loop is not stopping!
    {
        runPtr = runPtr->next;
    }

    this->tail= runPtr;
    delete runPtr;
}
```

for some reason the while loop is not stopping. what am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: These statements in sequence are quite nonsensical, and lead to memory leaks: `Node* runPtr= new Node;
    runPtr = this->head;`

Comment: `while(runPtr->next->next !=nullptr)` check `runPtr` and `runPtr->next` first.

Comment: the first two lines is a pattern I see surprisingly often. I am really curious, did you take it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not allocate new Node for the `runPtr`. It's a pointer that should point to an *already allocated* element in the list. Here you're just leaking memory.
2. Do not dereference pointer without validating it's not null. `runPtr` might be null, `runPtr->next` might be null too. In both cases you'll perform unauthorized memory access and either crash or get garbage.
3. You have to initialize the `head` pointer to the first element (or null) before attempting to iterate over the list.
4. You do not update the `next` pointer of the element that preceding the tail. After the first deletion this will result in a list that doesn't stop at null.